# What is the difference between Bootstrap.js, Bootstrap.min.js, Bootstrap-table.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Sorry for asking such a dumb question, But I am really not clear with these.

Bootstrap is really awesome library which save lot of work of developers.
Since it provide the lot of feature like

1. Save lots of time.
2. Responsive features.
3. Consistent design.
4. Easy to use.
5. Compatible with different browsers.

I have started working with bootstrap recently.
I am really confuse about few things.

When we download the Bootstrap we get a file structure like that.

```html
bootstrap/
|—— css/
|   |—— bootstrap.css
|   |—— bootstrap.min.css
|   |—— bootstrap-theme.css
|   |—— bootstrap-theme.min.css
|—— js/
|   |—— bootstrap.js
|   |—— bootstrap.min.js
|—— fonts/
|   |—— glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
|   |—— glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
|   |—— glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
|   |—— glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

So first Thing I want know is

1. What is the difference between  `bootstrap.js` and
   `bootstrap.min.js`.    When to use `bootstrap.js` and
   `bootstrap.min.js` ?
2. What is the difference between  `bootstrap.css` and
   `bootstrap.min.css`.    When to use `bootstrap.css` and
   `bootstrap.min.css` ?

Along with the above library Bootstrap provide some more library 
`Bootstrap Datatable` and `Bootstrap Table`

**Bootstrap Datatable**
[Bootstrap Datatable](https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap)

**Bootstrap Table**
[Bootstrap Table](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html)

3. What is the difference between `Bootstrap Datatable` and `Bootstrap
   Table`. When should I use `Bootstrap Datatable` and `BootstrapTable`.
4. If I include Bootstrap.js will I be able to use `Bootstrap Datatable` `Bootstrap Table`?.

**Bootstrap provide jar for both of them**

- `dataTables.bootstrap.js`
- `bootstrap-table.js`

*This is the screen short form official site of bootstrap*
[image]

Why I am asking because. I faced an strange issue. I was working with Boostrap Table. I include the `Bootstrap.js`, My Boostrap Table was not working, So I include the `bootstrap-table.js` and it worked.
then what is meaning of this?
[image]

At the same time when I was facing this issue I asked on `Stackoverflow` regarding this. and I got this.

[image]

after that I included every thing in my page.

```js
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="../resources/css/bootstrap-table.css" /> 
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="../resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="../resources/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" />
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="../resources/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" /> 
 
 <link media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="../resources/styles/base.css" />
 
 
<script src="../resources/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../resources/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="../resources/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
<script src="../resources/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../resources/js/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
```

and I faced a serious issue.What was happening is.
I had a `bootstrap modal table` and i was trying to populate the data from server side.

every thing was fine. but I dont know why the data was not populating in the table. I struggled around 2 days. It dint work. shutdown my system and slept.
but when I got in the morning and start the system. same code started working.
i dint notice I was relaxed thank God its working.

But today issue forced me to write such long question.
I forwarded my code to my senior. Its not working there. Even he struggled a lot. and after around 2 hours of struggled the same code started working I mean the data is populating in Bootstrap table. and I swear we we dint modified any thing.

What is the root cause of this issue?

Comment: `bootstrap.js` contains only standard bootstrap stuff, i.e. everything documented on the [official bootstrap site](http://getbootstrap.com). If you want to use external bootstrap plugin such as `datatable` or `bootstrap-table` you need to include their specific `js` and `css` files. BAnd the `.min` is only a [minified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29) version of the standard file. BTW, you should always include default boostrap files before any bootstrap plugin files.

Answer (score 4):

1. `bootstrap.js` is the standard version of Bootstrap's javascript. `bootstrap.min.js` is simply a minified version of the same file; line-breaks and comments are removed to reduce file-size.

In general, you should always use the minified version on production websites since it reduces page-load time for users, and Bootstrap recommends against modifying `bootstrap.js` directly.

2. The same applies to `bootsrap.css` and `bootstrap.min.css`.
3. (And 4) `Bootstrap Datatable` and `Bootstrap Table` are external libraries built by third-party developers *in the style* of Bootstrap. They're not officially supported, but you can use them if they suit your needs.